# How can i pass the request object in inclusion tag in django

Tags: python, django

I am overrding the admin `ChangeList` class and i am adding my own function there which requires request object like this

```
class MyChangeList(ChangeList):

    def sample(self, request):
        test = request.session["myvar"]
        return test
```

in the inclusion tag i need to use like this

```
@register.inclusion_tag("admin/change_list_results.html")
def my_result_list(cl):
    """
    Displays the headers and data list together
    """
    myvar = cl.sample()
    num_sorted_fields = 0
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `takes_context=True` to tag decorator.

```
@register.inclusion_tag("admin/change_list_results.html", takes_context=True)
def my_result_list(context, cl):
    """
    Displays the headers and data list together
    """
    myvar = cl.sample(context['request'])
    num_sorted_fields = 0
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)